# Basic Authentication em WebService Rest C#

Tags: c#, web-service, api, rest, restful

boa tarde!!!
Estou implementando um WebService Rest porém não estou conseguindo chamar o método BasicAuthentication de outra classe.

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "ConsultarCodigo/{cpfcnpj}")]
    public ConsultaPessoa GetPessoa(string cpfcnpj)
    {
        try
        {
            ConsultaPessoa consultaPessoa = new ConsultaPessoa();

            using (var conn = Connection.Conn)
            {
                IDbCommand comando = conn.CreateCommand();
                comando.CommandText = @"SELECT A.HANDLE,
                                               A.NOME
                                          FROM MS_PESSOA A
                                         WHERE A.CNPJCPFSEMMASCARA = '" + cpfcnpj + "'";

                using (IDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (!reader.Read())
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Pessoa não encontrada");
                    } 
                    consultaPessoa.codigo = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));
                    consultaPessoa.nome = reader.GetString(1);
                }

                return consultaPessoa;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new WebFaultException<string>(ex.Message, System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

Já tentei adicionar a classe na chamada onde é disponibilizado a URI do WebService mais mesmo assim sem sucesso, já pesquisei em vários sites mais não encontrei ninguém com este problema. Abaixo segue exemplo de de como estou chamando junto na URI.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "ConsultarCodigo/{cpfcnpj}"), BasicAuthenticationAttribute]
```

Porém mesmo assim ele não entra no método para realizar a autenticação do usuário.

Classe da autenticação.

```
public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization == null)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
        else
        {
            // Gets header parameters  
            string authenticationString = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
            string originalString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authenticationString));

            // Gets username and password  
            string username = originalString.Split(':')[0];
            string password = originalString.Split(':')[1];

            // Validate username and password  
            if (!ApiSecurity.VaidateUser(username, password))
            {
                // returns unauthorized error  
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }
        }

        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Alguém já pegou este problema antes ou sabe como resolver?
Deste já agradeço!

Comment: os arquivos estão no mesmo projeto? Estão no mesmo namespace? abs.

Comment: Sim, os arquivos estão no mesmo projeto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou decorar seu metodo com o atributo criado.

```
[BasicAuthentication]
public ConsultaPessoa GetPessoa(string cpfcnpj) { ... }
```

Comment: Já decorei o método com meu atributo, porém ele não chega a entrar neste atributo.